# Help with an inequality I've found

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality

I'm trying to prove the following inequality
$$ab\leq a\xi^{-1}(a)+b\xi(b)$$ $$\\ \forall a,b>0$$

where $\xi$ is a strictly increasing function with $\xi(0)=0$ and $\lim_{r\rightarrow +\infty} \xi(r)=+\infty$

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5):

Since $\xi$ is strictly increasing and $\xi(0)=0$, it is enough to show that either $\xi(b)\ge a$ or $\xi^{-1}(a)\ge b$.

Suppose that $\xi(b)<a$.  If $\xi^{-1}(a)<b$, then $a<\xi(b)$, which gives a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Draw the graph of $y = \xi(x)$. Place $a$ on the $x$-axis and $b$ on the $y$-axis. Then, interpret each product in your inequality as the area of a rectangle :

$Q_1 = \{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq a, 0 \leq y \leq b\}$

$Q_2 = \{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq a, 0 \leq y \leq f(a)\}$

$Q_3 = \{(x,y) : 0 \leq x \leq f^{-1}(b), 0 \leq y \leq b\}$

Your inequality is a trivial consequence of $Q_1 \subset Q_2 \cup Q_3$.